# chapter wise references in latex

Tags: latex, biblatex

How can I  add references at the end of every chapter in a latex file.
I am trying to use biblatex, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
\documentclass[draft,phd,12pt]{psuthesis}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,refsection=chapter,natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{library}
\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{Abdelaziz2007}
\printbibliography
```

The output is [image]

and no references

Comment: did you run `biber`? using the `refsection=chapter` seems correct, but it seems your reference key `Abdelaziz2007` is never resolved to the bibliographic data. You need to compile with the sequence `pdflatex file.tex`, `biber file.bcf`, `pdflatex file.tex` and one more `pdflatex file.tex` to get the references correctly resolved.
see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex) for an example on TeX.SX.

Comment: also replace the `\bibliography{...}` command with `\addbibresource{...}` as per 3.7.1 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).